# Should the oneM2M AE-ID attribute of the AE resource always be represented as SP-relative or absolute, not CSE-relative?

Tags: onem2m

If an AE registers with a CSE and gets assigned a C-AE-ID-Stem, should the AE-ID attribute of the new AE resource (as is received in the payload of the AE Create Response for instance) be the C-AE-ID-Stem, or the SP-relative-AE-ID?

Since the registration request itself, and subsequent requests from the AE to its CSE, are within the local CSE domain, a CSE-relative AE-ID is fine.  But if the AE wishes to use its AE-ID in a context outside of its CSE context, it needs the SP-relative (or absolute) version.

The specification doesn't seem to be clear on this specific point, though I did find this: in TS-0004 6.2.3 "oneM2M Entity Addressing", it defines "AE-ID" this way:

> AE-ID = absolute-AE-ID / SP-relative-AE-ID / S-AE-ID-Stem

From that, I think you could argue that the AE-ID attribute of the AE resource cannot be a C-AE-ID-Stem, in any context.  Is this thinking correct?

For example, if a CSE with CSE-ID of `/mycse` registers an AE with C-AE-ID-Stem of `Cmyae`, can (or should) the AE Create response look like this:

```json
{
  "m2m:ae": {
     "aei": "Cmyae"
  }
}
```

Or should it be this:

```json
{
  "m2m:ae": {
     "aei": "/mycse/Cmyae"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that the AE-ID can have any of the forms you mentioned, ie. CSE-relative, SP-relative, and Absolute. But those are defined for the context the AE-ID is actually used in: within the registrar CSE, the service provider domain, or even outside the service provider domain.

You may have a look at TS-0001, clause 7.2 "Identifier Formats". In the rather big table 7.2-1 in that clause there are the definitions for the AE-ID format for the different contexts.

An important part of the specification are the lines below that table that explain that not the AE but the CSE is responsible to do the conversion of identifiers when a request leaves, for example, a CSE-relative context (emphasis by me):

> The format (i.e. CSE-relative, SP-relative or absolute) of resource identifier (e.g. the To parameter, accessControlPolicyIDs attribute) shall be correctly set by the Originator in an initial request, **while the format of AE-ID or CSE-ID in the From parameter shall be set in a shortest format by the Originator in the initial request and it shall be converted in another format by the Registrar CSE or IN-CSE as the following**.
>
> When an AE is the Originator, the From parameter shall be in AE-ID-Stem. When the Registrar CSE receives the request, it shall convert the format into SP-relative AE-ID **in case the stem is CSE-relative and the To parameter refers to a resource hosted by a different CSE**.
>
> When an CSE is the Originator, the From parameter shall be in SP-relative CSE-ID.
>
> The IN-CSE shall convert the format of the From parameter in a request that is received from SP-relative to absolute if the To parameter refers to a resource is hosted by a CSE in a different M2M Service Provider Domain.

Also, see TS-0001 clause 7.1.2 "Application Entity Identifier (AE-ID)":

> The AE-ID, when used in the context of a specific CSE where the AE is registered, it is sufficient to be unique within the scope of that specific CSE. It is extended to become M2M Service Provider unique when used outside such specific CSE.

Im other words: The AE-ID attribute contains an identifier in CSE-relative format. The AE uses this identifier in its shortest form, e.g. for the originator, when sending requests via its registrar CSE, but the registrar CSE must extend it when, for example, forwarding the request to another CSE.

Comment: Thanks.  What prompted my question is that we have a case where the AE does not know the CSE-ID when it registers, yet wishes to use it out-of-band (non-Mca-interface) immediately after registration, and I was wondering if the Create Response was sufficient to inform the AE of the CSE-ID it just registered with.  If it was part of the AE-ID in the response, then the answer would be yes.  But if the AE-ID in the create response MUST be CSE-relative, then the AE cannot infer the CSE-ID.

Comment: I agree with all the points you make, regarding the context in which the AE-ID is used.  What about this from TS-0004 though: `AE-ID = absolute-AE-ID / SP-relative-AE-ID / S-AE-ID-Stem`?.  It seems to exclude C-AE-ID-Stem for some reason.  The spec also doesn't cover all the cases when the CSE should perform conversion.  For example, if an AE creates a subscription on a resource in the IN-CSE, is it the MN-CSE's responsibility to modify the contents of that request to change any AE-IDs in the notificationURI to SP-relative, before it forwards the request to the IN-CSE?

Comment: TS-0004 defines the protocol and data types, but not how is intended to use. That is defined in TS-0001. Since the AE-ID attribute may contain the different formats, it is mentioned there.
Changing identifiers: A CSE may change the identifier to a shorter format in resources, such as unstructured. Forwarding requests: One needs to ask whether the CSE can actually do this because this heavily depends on the context. The AE needs to do this, because only the AE knows where the targets in "nu" are actually hosted.

Comment: When sending requests via Mca the AE **must** know the CSE-ID, otherwise it cannot send the requests in the first place (i.e. it has to fill to "to" attribute). With the CSE-ID an AE cannot register itself. It may be that the AE is pre-registered by another entity (like a management system), but in this case the AE-ID as well as the CSE-ID (together with the address etc) needs to be made known to the AE by non-oneM2M means.

Comment: An AE can use CSE-relative addressing, so it doesn't need its CSE-ID.  If its known that there is only one CSE at a particular IP:port, why can't it register using CSE-relative addressing?  Can't it just set `to: "-"`?  That targets the cseBase resource using CSE-relative addressing.

Comment: You are right. you can address the CSEBase through the shortcut. But be aware that the dash character is a placeholder for the CSEBase's resource name, not its CSE-ID. But you could retrieve the CSEBase in order to determine the IDs you need. Also be aware that this depends on the binding and the request mapping. A direct connection to a port, like with http, would work, the MQTT binding really requires the CSE-ID. But if this works for you, this is fine. I think this is a good example for minimum knowledge for an AE. Just curious : how do you add authentication? Certificates?

Comment: Yes, we've been using coap and are now using coaps, and we've chosen a strategy of server-only-auth for the registration, then mutual auth (requiring a client cert) for Mca requests after registration.  And here lies the problem - for the certificate signing request, we require the SP-relative AE-ID, but we don't have the CSE-ID - yet we can't use the Mca to get it from the cseBase until we do the CSR to produce a client certificate!  So, even though CSE-relative addressing works for registration, we still need the CSE-ID by other means in order to progress.

Comment: I see. The CSE-ID should then a pre-shared information together with a certificate, distributed through a third-party trusted channel. Did you have a look at TS-0003? There are some procedures defined for third-party trust enablers.

Comment: Yes, we've looked at TS-0003, though our approach doesn't follow that to the letter, for various reasons

Comment: One more question about the AE-ID.  What about an announced AE with a C-type AE-ID?  In the announced AE on the IN-CSE, should the AE-ID attribute of the AEAnnc be the CSE-relative or SP-relative AE-ID?

Comment: It shall be SP-relative, like all other resource identifiers in other attributes. see TS-0001, clause 9.6.26.1: "If an attribute in the original resource has an identifier type (i.e. CSE-ID, AE-ID, resource identifier), the original resource Hosting CSE shall convert the value of this attribute to an identifier format (see table 7.2-1) required by the Receiver CSE."

Comment: Maybe just a comment on the discussion, when you register the AE using the "-" shortcut, you can know easily the CSE-ID as it is contained in the parentID attribute of the <AE> resource returned. So, you can build the SP-relative-AE-ID if needed.

Comment: @MiguelA.Reina doesn't that assume that the Resource ID of the CSEBase resource is the same as the CSE-ID?  I don't think that is a requirement, though I may be wrong.

Comment: I think this more like a convention. We will look into it.

Comment: I have come up with a solution to my dilemma in any case.  Responses have optional 'to' and 'from' attributes.  Our CSE can populate the 'from' attribute of responses with the CSE-ID, and that way the AE will get the CSE-ID from the response.

Comment: Is that a convention, to make the resourceID of the cseBase be the same as the CSE-ID?  We have not been doing that, but it seems like a nice convention.  Where would I find examples or documentation on that convention?  I guess that means that the SP-relative unstructured address of an MN-CSE would be essentially "/CSE-ID/CSE-ID"?

Comment: You are fully correct, CSE-ID and CSEBase resource ID are not necessarily the same. Although it is something common, we cannot guarantee that. We need to look at that. Maybe we should mandate the CSE to include the From parameter during the registration